# Android upload video using gdata to youtube?

Tags: android, youtube

In my application I need to upload a video to youtube from the gallery or a recording. I read

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos

and i have only youtube email account....

Which of the three approaches (browser based,direct,resumable) should I use?
and there are any source code??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find a particular post helpful, please please upvote it. If you find that a particular post answers your question, please accept it.

Comment: @Mayur patel Hey Dude i feeling trouble because of youtube direct which i choosen to upload videos on android application so please can u suggest about ur code or this application n help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use Direct Uploading because (I'm assuming) you're going to be receiving which video to upload via and Intent. [Here's a link](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/) to a project that demonstrates how to (among other things) directly upload to youtube from android. It should be exactly what you need to get started. I think the code you're looking for can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ytd/SubmitActivity.java#414).

Comment: You cant tell any forcefully to accept answer and upvote ,,i know this very you do nothing just search and tell me i l\know very well this..OK

Comment: The reason I've provided reference is because the question you've asked is incredibly general and any exact answer to it would include tons and tons of code. Rather than just duplicating the massive amounts of code that I would need to show you in order to specifically answer your question, I've given you a reference. If you want a more exact answer, please ask a more exact question.

Comment: I've also edited my response to include a specific link to the code in that project that does the uploading to youtube.